# Loading the next post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, smarty

I am trying to load the next post on my website but once I click it says post not found.
My code is below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "{$baseurl}/view/{$p.key}", success: function(result){
            $("#haha").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
```

`$p.key` is the key of the post or id which is being loaded from the key column in the `posts` table.

The idea is to load the next id each time I click on the button.

Comment: so $p.key it's the id of the current post or the next post?

Comment: p is the post 
key is the id (an encrypted key)
I want to get the next post somehow by going to the next key.

Comment: can you post or explain what code is executed when you go to /view/[post_key]?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use template strings?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: `${$baseurl}/view/${$p.key}`, success: function(result){
            $("#haha").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: would be perfect if i could load just the post @s hilch